# github create same tag for both the master and gh-pages

Tags: github, branch, tagging

I've created a repository on Github, and at some point I've created a tag on the master. Now for the branche gh-pages I want to create a tag also with the same name. But thats not possible. I can see that the tag only applies to the master, so why can't I apply the same tag name on different branches ?

cheers
Luca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't apply the "same tag" multiple times, as a tag is there to reference one and only one commit.
(See "[Tag multiple branches in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972866/tag-multiple-branches-in-git)" for more)

If you `git checkout -b gh-pages`  from `master`, then you will be on a commit referenced both by `master` and the new branch `gh-pages`.
In that instance, *one* tag would be valid for both branches.

But once you start to create new commits in the new branches, you will apply one uniquely named tag to commits in that new branch only.

Kep in mind however that a tag isn't linked to a branch (if you were to rebase that branch on top of `master`, and then merge `master`... you would end up again with one `HEAD` referenced by the two branches: all the tags would be again part of the two branches).
A tag is only linked to a commit.

---

Update August 2016: **[Simpler GitHub Pages publishing](https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing)** now allows to keep your page files in a subfolder of the *same* branch (no more `gh-pages` needed):

[image: Now you can select a source in your repository settings and GitHub Pages will look for your content there.]

So here, you could tag `master`, referring to both contents.